# Handling eqaulity constraints in genetic algorithms

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms, constraint-satisfaction, evolutionary-computing

I am trying to solve an optimization problem with strength pareto algorithm (SPEA2). My decision variable have lower and upper bounds as well as an equality constraint (sum(dp) = 1). I am unable to handle equality constraints. Please advise.[image: constraints]

Comment: Can you give a self-contained description of the optimization problem?  What objective function are you trying to maximize?  Are there any other constraints?  Are there any constraints that relate $\phi_j$ to $p_j$?

Comment: For this specific case, just have your algorithm directly model $p_1$ through $p_{ n-1}$, and set $p_n$ equal to 1 minus their sum. That way, you're guaranteed to meet the equality constraint.